# Autopost from Drupal to Pinterest?

Tags: nodes, media

Is there a way to autopost images that are inside nodes from Drupal to Pinterest?

Answer (score 1):

You could set something like this up, by using Rules+Mime Mail+IFTTT.

1. Set up a recipe in IFTTT that

   - Gets triggered when it receives an email by a specific address
   - Posts on Pinterest as a reaction, using the attachment in the email
   - https://ifttt.com/channels/email/triggers/50-send-ifttt-an-email-tagged
2. Configure Rules to send an email on an appropriate event, e.g. node updated/created

   - You need to use the Mime Mail to get the option to add attachments to your outgoing email
   - Check out this video for further information: [Learn Drupal - Send email with attachments via Rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-5pu1TSFIg)
   - You may need to configure your Drupal instance to use SMTP authentication on yor outgoing server to make it work with IFTTT. The [PHPMailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer) module will probably help you with this.

Hope this helps, good luck!